# Spark: Executor Cores not reading files parallely

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, io, hadoop-yarn

I have a `spark` application with `yarn scheduler` (`yarn-client` mode with `fair` scheduler), where `Stage`-1 is reading 160+ files from `S3`. The snapshot showing `Event Timeline` is shown below:

[image]

**Question**:

What is the reason why the files are not being read parallely by two `cores` in an `executor`? What factors determine how many `physical cores` will be used for `spark-cores`? Is there a setting to guarantee that?

**EDIT-1**

Quoting from [`Spark Yarn Configuration article`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#important-notes) :
*"Whether core requests are honored in scheduling decisions depends on which scheduler is in use and how it is configured."*

It seems cores requests are governed by Yarn scheduler settings. Can someone point me which settings are responsible for this?

Comment: do you have some code to show?

Comment: are you able to solve this problem?

Comment: Not entirely. But it was observed yarn launches the executors which can get launched on one machine. The executor cores are supposed to read the file/blocks in parallel, but it depends on the cpu cores and io-channels on the machine (which is shared by all executor processes). By Increasing executor cores, I managed to get some benefit.